# I cannot get venobox to work on my website

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I am trying to use venobox on my website so when the user clicks on a picture, a box is opened and it will display a  YouTube but I cannot get it to work please help me fix what I am doing wrong.
My code: http://hastebin.com/awuxarivoj.html

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

your code misses venobox's css and js, and there's no plugin initialization.
I only see two links with the class "venobox". Also, youtube links should have the data-vbtype="youtube". please read the [documentation](http://veno.es/venobox)

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you didn't properly linked required venobox plugin files.
Download venobox plugin and link it in your html document.
Also take care of ordering of linking the plugins